# How to read data from mongodb by input value and display it using ejs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to search mongodb on a post request for all products in my database. Everything is working except the post request. The request goes through but no data is given back. I do not see a problem with the database.

```
  const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const app = express();

    app.set("view engine", "ejs");

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.static("public"));

    mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://x:origisgood@cluster0.d6rzu.mongodb.net/productsDB? 
    retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
    );

   const productsSchema = {
   name: String,
   price: Number,
   img: String,
   };

   const Product = mongoose.model("product", productsSchema);

   app.get("/", function (req, res) {
   res.send(__dirname + "/index.html");
   });

   app.post("/", function (req, res) {
   const productName = req.body.productName;
   Product.find({ name: productName }, function (err, foundProducts) {
    res.render("home", {
      name: foundProducts.name,
      price: foundProducts.price,
      img: foundProducts.img,
    });
   });
   });

  app.listen(3001, function () {
  console.log("Server started successfully");
  });
```

index.html to be displayed before everything else

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>X</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="productName"
        placeholder="Search for a product"
      />
      <button type="submit" name="Search">Search</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.ejs to be displayed when a product is searched up

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>X</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= name %></h1>
    <% var imgwostr = img; %>
    <% imgwostr = str.replace(/^"|"$/g, ""); %>
    <img src="<%= imgwostr %>" alt="">
    <p><%= price %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the db returns a list of documents that you treat as one.
Your `foundProducts` object is actually an array of type `Product`, even if there is only one product it is still an array which means that if you want to get the value back you would need to specify an index of the item you want to get.
Something like this should work:

```js
Product.find({ name: productName }, function (err, foundProducts) {
    const product = foundProducts[0];

    if (!product) {
        res.render('notfound');
    }

    res.render("home", {
      name: product.name,
      price: product.price,
      img: product.img,
    });
}
```

Notice that if the product is not found you would need to render another page because you will have nothing to display.